# Unity Vuforia asking for a useless permission access

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am currently making an Android application with Unity 2017.3.0f3 and Vuforia 7.0.36.

At startup, the application asks for

- camera permission (that's ok and logic)
- "Pictures, file and media on this device" (I don't understand this one !)

After further investigations, I discovered that during the creation of the Android Manifest file, Vuforia (VuforiaWrapper) was adding:

- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

That is why the application is asking for the second permission I guess.

Hence, why is Vuforia adding this aggresive "pictures, files and media" access ?

How to remove that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove them by editing vuforia manifest file. If permission still persist, you can export the project to android studio and remove permissions from there.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to make it directly from Unity if possible. I cannot find any manifest file in vuforia folder of my unity project. Do you know where the "vuforia manifest file" is located in my project hierarchy ?

Comment: probably in editor folder under vuforia. you can search from IDE for whole project if it is being added on unity build time.